# Configuring proxy settings for goproxy

Tags: macos, go, proxy, configuration

I'm trying to use goproxy as an alternative to fiddler on mac OSX,

I wrote the following code, and succeeded to run it:

```
package main

import (
"flag"
"log"
"net/http"
"gopkg.in/elazarl/goproxy.v1"
)

func main() {
    verbose := flag.Bool("v", false, "should every proxy request be logged 
to stdout")
    addr := flag.String("addr", ":8080", "proxy listen address")

    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.Verbose = *verbose
    proxy.OnResponse().DoFunc(func(resp *http.Response, ctx 
*goproxy.ProxyCtx) *http.Response {
        contentType := resp.Header.Get("Content-Type")
        if contentType == "application/javascript" || contentType == "application/x-javascript" {
        // Do something...
        }
        return resp
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, proxy))
 }
```

According to goproxy documentation I need to configure web proxy & secure web proxy:
[image]

I have put multiple breakpoints and run the code in debug, tried to access a website but I can't get it to stop on the breakpoint..

I think I'm missing something in the proxy settings maybe.

Comment: Breakpoints using what? Delve? When you say you "run the code in debug" do you mean *in the debugger*?

Comment: @Adrian I'm using jetbrains GoLand IDE.

Comment: Uncheck Automatic proxy conf

Comment: @nicky this doesn't help, I noticed that the code works fine when using http requests but not https requests.

Comment: what is https conf, both runs in diff port http and https